# Cycles texture paint independently of UV mapping

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I have created a section of road that has a tiled asphalt image texture with a combination of nodes setup. I then physically applied an array modifier to make it a long length of road and now want to manually paint some imperfections like tire marks and cracks etc.

When I try to texture paint in one place using stencil brush option it tiles the paint as though I am modifying the original image texture.

Is there a way to paint anywhere on the entire object on top of the original texture so the imperfections are placed independently of the original UV mapping? I wasn’t sure if I might have to map differently or there is a specific method I’m not aware of.

Comment: If you keep using the Array modifier, I don't think it's possible to make such wide texture painting over it all. One way to handle this might be to make smaller, transparent mesh-planes on top (but very close to the surface) of the road and paint the marks on those. Then you could copy that mesh-plane with the marks to other locations of that road also.

Comment: I have “applied” the array modifier so it is a single long mesh made up of dozens of individual faces. I then UV projected from view and scaled to maintain the continual tiled effect. This will be animated and I think extra faces with the added detail may risk flicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can still use two UV mapped textures but one is the perfect version, and the other is a damaged version. Here in my example, the procedural texture is set to generated coordinate and it is used to reveal the purple color by driving the mix factor of the color mix node. You can see I set the arrays to leave some space so the procedural texture effect is apparent. Better to experiment with procedural textures to see what is the best option here, but this is the best option for now until we get some kind of texture modifier that works on top of arrays and allows a separate uv mapping that includes the rest of the generated mesh.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Craig am I correct in what your saying  is the Voronoi mixed in (or other methods) is scaled or adjusted to suit the look I am after? Also just to clarify the array has been applied so it is a single object made up of dozens of faces

Comment: Yes, the array has been applied in your example but not in mine - mine is an active array set up. The voronoi acts across the whole modified space and not just per face as the UV does. If you want even more control, you can set up a second UV mapping that allows you to then paint on a second image across the whole mesh without losing your tiled image on the first mapping.

Comment: A second UV independent of the first mapping sounds like a possible solution and would give me more control over placement of added details. I wasn’t aware that was possible though so I’ll have to research it. Is that done through the existing node structure or separately?

Comment: In the properties editor add a new uv map and make that the active one and then go about unwrapping all the new faces with something like smart unwrap. Adding an attribute node you can reference the new up map and then set up a new image texture.

Comment: that seems to work as long as I use an attribute node for each image/uv map and with some tweaking hopefully will give some nice results